# How to create database object in java?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I would like to ask if there is some way to make instantiation of some database in java.

For example

```
MySQLDatabase db = new MySQLDatabase(password, name);
```

Is this possible? The reason is I need it is that I want to work with large datasets quickly. Moreover, it is easier to do data transformations in some DB.

Comment: Are you referring to other languages/frameworks where you have experience working like this? Because if so, please state them.

Comment: If you want to work on large datasets quickly, you may be better of writing it in Java, rather than passing data back and forth to a database.

Comment: Have a look at JDBC: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/

Answer (score 2):

[HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking for but MySql do have a [JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j.html) that you can use to connect to a MySql database from Java.